# ng-click not working for no reason

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, button, model-view-controller

This makes no sense. I have one ng-click working and the rest don't work. I wish I could tell you more, but that is literally it. Please help me someone, I don't know how this could possibly be happening.

js Script

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    //function refresh(){ 
    //$http.get("/Background/KralovecRecords.json").success(function (response) {
    //    alert("Affirmative, Andrew. I read you.");
    //    $scope.names = response;
    //}).error(function (error) {
    //    alert("Get Error: "+error);
    //});

    //}

    function refresh() {
       $http.get("/Database/KralovecSelect").success(function (response) {
         alert("Affirmative, Andrew. I read you.");
         $scope.names = response;
       }).error(function (error) {
         alert("Get Error: " + error);
       });
    }
    refresh();

    // Version
    function getVersion() {
       $http.get("/Database/KralovecVersion").success(function (response) {
         alert("" + response);
       }).error(function (error) {
         alert("Get Error: " + error);
       });
    }

    // Works
    $scope.editItem = function (id) {
        alert("Course"+id);
        $http.post('/Database/KralovecMessage',id).success(function (response) {
            console.log("Response"+respsone); 
            $scope.contact = response;
            refresh();
        });
    }

    // Will not work
    $scope.dropItem = function (id) {
       alert("Course" + id);
    }

    // Will not work 
    $scope.addCourse = function (){
        alert("Course");
    }
});
```

HTML Page

```
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Global.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped ajk-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
                    <th>Course</th>
                    <th>Section</th>
                    <th>Max</th>
                    <th>CRN</th>
                    <th>Instructor</th>
                    <th>Days</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Room</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input class="form-control has-error" ng-model="contact.Course"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control has-error" ng-model="contact.Section"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control has-error" ng-model="contact.Max"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control has-error" ng-model="contact.CRN"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control has-error" ng-model="contact.Instructor"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control has-error" ng-model="contact.Days"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control has-error" ng-model="contact.Time"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control has-error" ng-model="contact.Room"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control has-error" ng-model="contact.Notes"></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="alert(5);">Add Contact</button></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="alert('Please wokr');">Update</button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="alert('Why god?');">Clear</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="contact in names">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
                <td>{{contact.Course}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Section}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Max}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.CRN}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Instructor}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Days}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Time}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Room}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Notes}}</td>
                <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Drop"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Drop" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#drop" ng-click="dropItem(contact.Course)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>
                <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" ng-click="editItem(contact.Course)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>New Database</th>
                <th>
                    <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add New Database"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="add_database" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view" ng-click="addDB(')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></p>
                    <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Update Database"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="update_database" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view" ng-click="updateDB(DB_INPUT)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></span></button></p>
                    <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Upload file to Database"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="add_file_database" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view" ng-click="fileAddDB(DB_INPUT)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span></button></p>
                </th>
                <th colspan="2"><input class="form-control has-error" ng-model="DB_INPUT"></th>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Which ng-click is working?

Comment: <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" ng-click="editItem(contact.Course)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td>

Comment: I already saw that, looking for the answer, the alerts were just for visual effect

Comment: What if you remove addDB(') from the html? That one should not be working.

Comment: I deleted most of the stuff, thinking there was a problem with the code, instead of a problem with angular

Comment: Can you create a plunkr?

Comment: Why, why cant i just have more than one button ?

Comment: Are you seeing errors on your console when trying to use the clicks?

Comment: you should be able to have more than one button. Try removing the $http.post from the edit function and try the other buttons.

Comment: One of the first things i tried. Didn't fix it

Comment: Try adding the refresh(); function at the bottom of the controller

Comment: Yeah, that wont matter

Comment: Thats just to reload the table contacts after the edits, which cant happend because i need more than one button

Comment: one thing that I see, declare at the beginning of the controller $scope.names = []; and then replace $scope.names = response with angular.extend($scope.names, response);

Comment: Sure, but wont fix the buttons

Comment: do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: here's a plunkr for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/71q9WbcCWSR9x25cI4Vb?p=preview everything seems to be working fine. I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ng-controller="customersCtrl"` to the table on top.

Example:

`<table class="table table-bordered table-striped ajk-table" ng-controller="customersCtrl">`

I'm presuming you've already added `ng-app` to the body or parent element.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is the call to alert() inside of ng-click. Angular is looking on the $scope of your directive or controller or whatever scope that element belongs to ($rootScope by default). 
i.e. this will work:

```
<script>
app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myAlert = function(){
        alert('this alert works!')
    };
});
</script>    
<button ng-controller="customersCtrl" ng-click='myAlert()'>
```

Comment: The alerts were just visual, i had stuff inside the functions, and they didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your html structure, I presume you are using bootstrap along with the modal dialog. I guess the modal is getting fired on click and as such your code isn't working because its not sure whether to show the modal or fire the ng-click event.

Just to be clear on this you can try:

1.removing the data-attributes and see what happens
2. Swap the below 2 lines and see if editItem function works instead of dropItem function.

```
<td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Drop"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Drop" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#drop" ng-click="dropItem(contact.Course)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>
                <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" ng-click="editItem(contact.Course)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td>
```

Bottom line is clean up your code and remove the unnecessary data-attributes for debugging purpose and see if console throws any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-click if you want to use a function on your scope. Since you're just calling alert, which is a host function, you can use 'onclick' rather than 'ng-click'